# UI delayed showing with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I defined an AsyncTask in a button's onclicklistener, and once user clicks the button, ideally progress dialog shows while asynctask downloading.

However, progress dialog just flashes in and disappears before the results returned, and the button gets focused while the asynctask works in the background.

Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong here? Code snippet:

```
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginActivity)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> downloadTask= new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String data = Service.getSomeData();
                            context.getContentResolver.notifyChange("content://some_url");
                        return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if(progressDialog== null) return;
                    if(progressDialog!=null) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }
            };

            progressDialog.show();

            downloadTask.execute();
            try{
                downloadTask.get();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `get()`

```
downloadTask.get();
```

this is a blocking call. From the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Just use `execute()` as you are then do what you need with the results in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: i'll give a shot on this one!

Comment: Ok, you may have other issues but this was the first thing that popped out at me. Let me know how it works

Comment: it worked! but could you please let me know the other issues you found here? thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't see anything else too obvious. I was just warning you that if removing that didn't work then you may have something else wrong, also but that was certainly a problem. If it is working now then you should be good. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

show the progressDialog on the `onPreExecute` which need to be writen, and it will run on the UI thread, not in background ( android 4 )

also I would call the async task on a `new Handler().post(myAsynctaskcaller)`

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       progressDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. i will give a try on this one next time. cheers!